# simple tense and time and composite sentence

Tags: time

If the eating meal starts at 7:00 AM and finishes at 8:00 AM. the drinking liquor starts at 8:00 AM and finishes at 9:00 AM.

can I say that :

1. I drank the liquor after I ate the meal.
2. I drank the liquor for 60 minutes after I ate the meal for 60 minutes.

moreover If the eating meal starts at 7:00 AM and finishes at 8:00 AM. the drinking liquor starts at 8:10 AM and finishes at 9:10 AM. how do I say ?

Comment: Yes, yes, and as you basically said "The eating meal starts at 7:00 AM and finishes at 8:00 AM. The drinking liquor starts at 8:10 AM and finishes at 9:10 AM."

Comment: This is really teetering on the edge of word golf. This question really needs to ask a *meaningful* language question, rather than just "what happened when" puzzles.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the two sentences presented. However, I think you can improve them a little bit as follows:

I had the liquor right/just/immediately after the meal.

I had the liquor right after the meal, which took me an hour each.

I had the liquor 10 minutes after the meal, which took me an hour each.

Comment: If the eating meal starts at 7:00 AM and finishes at 8:00 AM. the drinking liquor starts at 7:00 AM and finishes at 8:00 AM. what should I say ?

Comment: I ate my meal drinking some liquor at the same time